# Possibilities of getting tex code from a beamer pdf?

Tags: beamer

Suppose I have a pdf copy of the beamer presentation and would like to get the texcode for it with out retyping it as it is quite long, is there a possibility of being able to get the tex code from the saved pdf or is this impossible ? I am not looking for something that includes a page using `include page` package as I would like to make new points for example.

Thanks and please let me know if there are ambiguities.

Comment: It's like getting the apples back from an apple pie, I'm afraid. `;-)`

Comment: Lol, If only one could obtain the source code from the pdf file, life would be much more convenient. Would the best way either to reference it through `include pages` or retype it ?

Comment: It *is* possible to embed the TeX code in the PDF file for later retrieval, but it's an action that must be specifically requested at compile time. With good OCR software you can get the text, at least.

Comment: Ah, well since the content is mostly latex equations, is it possible for me to just copy the compiled equations and maybe have some software that will minimize the amount of editing involved on my part ? If, so what would be the best recommended way to do this ?

Comment: The recommended way would be to retype it. as it is a presentation I assume it isn't a thousand pages long, so retyping is likely to be the most effective way.

Comment: You can probably get the text more easily with something like `pdftotext` than OCR.  But if it is mostly equations and layout, retyping will probably be more efficient.

Comment: The following workflow can get you the source code: Open pdf file, copy author name, paste it into a search engine, get the email address, write a polite mail asking for the source code, wait for the reply.

Comment: There is a nice Wolfram-alpha demo here: http://webdemo.myscript.com/#/demo/equation that transfrom handwritten equation to TeX, and is quite effective. I do not know if it's possible to feed a bitmap to it (I don't think, but...)

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for the suggestions, now if someone can type in an answer, I will accept it :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's impossible.

Long Answer: although sometime it's possible to bundle the source document in a PDF,  that must be done at the time of the creation of the document (and I do not think that `pdflatex` and co. have this option), in general the process is not reversible.

The options are:

1. contact the authors and ask if they are ok with sharing the source;
2. rewrite the document<sup>**1**</sup>. You can try to use tools like, for example, [`pdftotext`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) to extract the plain text content, some kind of PDF editor like [`inkscape`](https://inkscape.org/en/) for the images, and maybe [this nice site](http://webdemo.myscript.com/#/demo/equation) to help with the equation.

<sup>**1**</sup> Obviously, if the license of the document allows it; and, *ça va san dire*, citing the sources... ;-)

Comment: about bundling the source document with the PDF, packages [attachfile2](http://ctan.org/pkg/attachfile2) and [embedfile](http://ctan.org/pkg/embedfile) are relevant for compilation with `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 1):

For people looking at this question now, years later: you can use [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) to do this. It allows you to 'snip' parts of your screen and convert an image (handwritten or just a formatted mathematical equation) to LaTeX instantly. It works great and is use to use.

[image: 2]

Comment: Impressive, but they misspelled LaTeX on their front page.